# JavaScript string to JSON conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am receiving CLOB data in java which i am converting to string and it becomes something like:

```
"{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40}"
```

and I need this string to pass in an array like

```
[{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40}].
```

I tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringify which are helping.

How do i do it? Please help

Comment: You can't use JSON.stringify because it's not an object or an array and you can't use JSON.parse because it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Just add parentheses around your string to make it JSON?

Comment: @JuanMendes still wouldn't be valid because the keys must be put in quotes

Comment: Besides the obvious missing `[` and `]`, JSON is also only valid if all *keys* (such as `ab` and `cd`) are quoted: `{ "ab": -73 , "cd": 40 },  ... etc ... }`. If you can't teach your server better JSON manners, then you're going to have a hard time fixing the garbage that it produces...

Comment: @vlaz That's true, they would have to use eval :)

Comment: Alternatively, (if possible) get properly formatted input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the serialization of your input, it would be best to convert that to valid JSON.

But you can convert this fairly readily:

```js
const convert = str => JSON.parse(`[${str.replace(/(\w+)\:/g, '"$1":')}]`)

const input = "{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40}"

console.log(convert(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` to convert your string into an object/array of objects. See snippet.

Please be careful, using this solution, with where this input is coming from. `eval` will attempt to execute any string as JavaScript so if someone were to inject malicious script into the CLOB data, it would potentially run if the `([` didn't break it.

```js
const str = "{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40}";
const obj = eval('([' + str + '])');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a sustainable solution but if you just need to get the work done, here is a possible but ugly solution. But i strongly recommend to fix that broken JSON in the first place.

```
let string = '{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40},{ab:-73,cd:40}'

const fixBrokenJson = string => {
  let array = string.split('},')
    .map(item => item.replace('{', '').replace('}', ''))
    .map(item => item.split(','))

  array = array.map(arr => {
    let result = {}
    arr.forEach(strObj => {
      const _obj = strObj.split(':')
      result = {
        ...result,
        ...{[_obj[0]]: Number(_obj[1])},
      }
    })
    return result
  })
  return array
}
console.log(fixBrokenJson(string))


  // Output
  [
    {ab: -73, cd: 40},
    {ab: -73, cd: 40},
    {ab: -73, cd: 40},
    {ab: -73, cd: 40},
    {ab: -73, cd: 40},
  ]
```